# Pass data from class select to get route

Tags: html, laravel, href

how can I pass data from this form to my route?

```
<div class="panel-body">
    {!! Form::open(array('route'=>'show.exclusion')) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('choosegroup', 'Wähle eine Gruppe')}}
            <select class="form-control m-bot15" name="idgroup">
                @foreach($groups as $group)
                    <option value="{{ $group->id }}">{{ $group->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{Form::submit('Search',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-close" href="{{ route('home') }}">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

This is my route...

```
Route::get('exclusion/show/{id}', 'ExclusionController@show')->name('show.exclusion');
```

First I put the $group->id parameter into the array route part. But I cannot use them at this point of my code.

Any Ideas?

EDIT:

```
public function show($id)
{  
    $member = Nerd::find($id);

    return view('groups.test')->with('member', $member);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the controller method for `ExclusionController@show`?

Comment: Now, you can see my controller above.

Comment: Why are you submitting your form to this controller method?

Comment: Is this controller method wrong? I need only a member group von the database filtered on that input group in the select option field. Which method would be better?

Comment: You want to be submitting the form to the he method that is going to handle the form request. Looking a that method it isn't set up to handle any data submitted to it. Also, I would imagine that you want to be passing `$member->id` to the route not a `$group->id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the whole Request to the function. Than it is possible to get the Values of your Formdata.

```html
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
        $idgroup = $request->input('idgroup');
}
```

For more details have a look here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request()` method to fetch form data without any class dependencies.

For example:
`request()->id;`